# Where should I put an msi file in my cookbook?

Tags: windows, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I am removing a windows program by using the MSI with the windows_package resource:

```
windows_package 'SomeShittyProgram' do
  action :remove
  source 'c:\temp\msi'
end
```

Is it safe to have a (small) MSI file in my cookbook? How can I have chef deliver that file to the node?

I'd use remote_file to pull it from a network location, but that makes testing the cookbook in test kitchen difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we *strongly* recommend against doing this (storing large binary files in a cookbook), but you can do it. Put the file under `./files/whatever.msi` and then in recipe code use `cookbook_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/whatever.msi" do source "whatever.msi" end` and then use a `windows_package` resource to do the install.

The reason to not do this is that Chef is not a good file storage system. Using something like S3, Artifactory, or even an HTTP server plus `remote_file` gives you a lot more flexibility. This tends to rapidly bloat your git repo.